# Javascript Array of Objects as Table data

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a pure JS 6x6 grid style game in which each grid cell should alternate between 3 colours (one at a time) when clicked once. I'm running into two issues: I'd like to display each cell blank, simply containing the colour, but I can't seem to get this to work without having to display text in the cell.

I'm also trying to figure out a way to "toggle" between three colours. My use of toggle works for two colours, but I'm not quite sure if/how I can add a third option as it seems to work based on true/false.

Is there any way I can display an "empty" cell here? Should I scrap my method of attack for changing colours? Apologies if my code is all over the place, I've been looking at this for too long.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grid</title>
    <style>
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.grey{
background-color:grey;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tile {
  cursor: pointer;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    //6x6 array
var solutionArray = new Array(6);
solutionArray[0] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[1] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[2] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[3] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[4] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[5] = new Array(6);

    //6x6 array
var userArray = new Array(6);
userArray[0] = new Array(6);
userArray[1] = new Array(6);
userArray[2] = new Array(6);
userArray[3] = new Array(6);
userArray[4] = new Array(6);
userArray[5] = new Array(6);

var tile = {colour1:blue, colour2:white, colour3:grey};
var z = "";
var blue = tile.colour1 = "blue";
var white = tile.colour2 = "white";
var grey = tile.colour = "grey";

solutionArray[0][0] = blue;
solutionArray[0][1] = white;
solutionArray[0][2] = blue;
solutionArray[0][3] = blue;
solutionArray[0][4] = white;
solutionArray[0][5] = blue;

solutionArray[1][0] = white;
solutionArray[1][1] = blue;
solutionArray[1][2] = white;
solutionArray[1][3] = blue;
solutionArray[1][4] = blue;
solutionArray[1][5] = white;

solutionArray[2][0] = blue;
solutionArray[2][1] = white;
solutionArray[2][2] = blue;
solutionArray[2][3] = white;
solutionArray[2][4] = white;
solutionArray[2][5] = blue;

solutionArray[3][0] = white;
solutionArray[3][1] = blue;
solutionArray[3][2] = white;
solutionArray[3][3] = white;
solutionArray[3][4] = blue;
solutionArray[3][5] = blue;

solutionArray[4][0] = blue;
solutionArray[4][1] = blue;
solutionArray[4][2] = white;
solutionArray[4][3] = blue;
solutionArray[4][4] = white;
solutionArray[4][5] = white;

solutionArray[5][0] = blue;
solutionArray[5][1] = white;
solutionArray[5][2] = blue;
solutionArray[5][3] = white;
solutionArray[5][4] = blue;
solutionArray[5][5] = white;

//USER ARRAY
userArray[0][0] = blue;
userArray[0][1] = grey;
userArray[0][2] = grey;
userArray[0][3] = grey;
userArray[0][4] = grey;
userArray[0][5] = blue;

userArray[1][0] = grey;
userArray[1][1] = blue;
userArray[1][2] = grey;
userArray[1][3] = grey;
userArray[1][4] = grey;
userArray[1][5] = white;

userArray[2][0] = grey;
userArray[2][1] = grey;
userArray[2][2] = blue;
userArray[2][3] = grey;
userArray[2][4] = white;
userArray[2][5] = grey;

userArray[3][0] = grey;
userArray[3][1] = grey;
userArray[3][2] = grey;
userArray[3][3] = grey;
userArray[3][4] = grey;
userArray[3][5] = grey;

userArray[4][0] = grey;
userArray[4][1] = grey;
userArray[4][2] = white;
userArray[4][3] = grey;
userArray[4][4] = grey;
userArray[4][5] = white;

userArray[5][0] = grey;
userArray[5][1] = grey;
userArray[5][2] = grey;
userArray[5][3] = grey;
userArray[5][4] = blue;
userArray[5][5] = white;

var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "gridTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  //output the row tag
  var y = document.createElement("TR");
  y.setAttribute("id", "row" + i);
  document.getElementById("gridTable").appendChild(y)

  for (j = 0; j < userArray.length; j++) {

    ///output the td tag
    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    if (userArray[i][j] == blue) {
      z.setAttribute("class", "blueTile tile blue");
    } else if (userArray[i][j] == white) {
      z.setAttribute("class", "blueTile tile");
    } else if (userArray[i][j] == grey) {
      z.setAttribute("class", "blueTile tile grey");
    }
    var t = document.createTextNode(userArray[i][j]);
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("row" + i).appendChild(z);

  }

}

document.querySelector("#gridTable").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "TD" && event.target.classList.contains("blueTile")) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("blue");
  }
});
document.querySelector("#gridTable").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "TD" && event.target.classList.contains("blueTile")) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("grey");
  }
    });



    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First issue: You should add "empty-cells: show" on table tag (this is needed for some of the browsers).
- Second issue: Just use simple logic. toggle function you are using is not inteded for your goals. See the code below. In general the whole code could be optimized a lot.

I have tested that code and both issues are resolved:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Grid</title>
    <style>
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.grey{
background-color:grey;
}

.white{
background-color:white;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}
table td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

    //6x6 array
var solutionArray = new Array(6);
solutionArray[0] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[1] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[2] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[3] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[4] = new Array(6);
solutionArray[5] = new Array(6);

    //6x6 array
var userArray = new Array(6);
userArray[0] = new Array(6);
userArray[1] = new Array(6);
userArray[2] = new Array(6);
userArray[3] = new Array(6);
userArray[4] = new Array(6);
userArray[5] = new Array(6);

var tile = {colour1:blue, colour2:white, colour3:grey};
var z = "";
var blue = tile.colour1 = "blue";
var white = tile.colour2 = "white";
var grey = tile.colour = "grey";

solutionArray[0][0] = blue;
solutionArray[0][1] = white;
solutionArray[0][2] = blue;
solutionArray[0][3] = blue;
solutionArray[0][4] = white;
solutionArray[0][5] = blue;

solutionArray[1][0] = white;
solutionArray[1][1] = blue;
solutionArray[1][2] = white;
solutionArray[1][3] = blue;
solutionArray[1][4] = blue;
solutionArray[1][5] = white;

solutionArray[2][0] = blue;
solutionArray[2][1] = white;
solutionArray[2][2] = blue;
solutionArray[2][3] = white;
solutionArray[2][4] = white;
solutionArray[2][5] = blue;

solutionArray[3][0] = white;
solutionArray[3][1] = blue;
solutionArray[3][2] = white;
solutionArray[3][3] = white;
solutionArray[3][4] = blue;
solutionArray[3][5] = blue;

solutionArray[4][0] = blue;
solutionArray[4][1] = blue;
solutionArray[4][2] = white;
solutionArray[4][3] = blue;
solutionArray[4][4] = white;
solutionArray[4][5] = white;

solutionArray[5][0] = blue;
solutionArray[5][1] = white;
solutionArray[5][2] = blue;
solutionArray[5][3] = white;
solutionArray[5][4] = blue;
solutionArray[5][5] = white;

//USER ARRAY
userArray[0][0] = blue;
userArray[0][1] = grey;
userArray[0][2] = grey;
userArray[0][3] = grey;
userArray[0][4] = grey;
userArray[0][5] = blue;

userArray[1][0] = grey;
userArray[1][1] = blue;
userArray[1][2] = grey;
userArray[1][3] = grey;
userArray[1][4] = grey;
userArray[1][5] = white;

userArray[2][0] = grey;
userArray[2][1] = grey;
userArray[2][2] = blue;
userArray[2][3] = grey;
userArray[2][4] = white;
userArray[2][5] = grey;

userArray[3][0] = grey;
userArray[3][1] = grey;
userArray[3][2] = grey;
userArray[3][3] = grey;
userArray[3][4] = grey;
userArray[3][5] = grey;

userArray[4][0] = grey;
userArray[4][1] = grey;
userArray[4][2] = white;
userArray[4][3] = grey;
userArray[4][4] = grey;
userArray[4][5] = white;

userArray[5][0] = grey;
userArray[5][1] = grey;
userArray[5][2] = grey;
userArray[5][3] = grey;
userArray[5][4] = blue;
userArray[5][5] = white;

var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "gridTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  //output the row tag
  var y = document.createElement("TR");
  y.setAttribute("id", "row" + i);
  document.getElementById("gridTable").appendChild(y)

  for (j = 0; j < userArray.length; j++) {

    ///output the td tag
    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    if (userArray[i][j] == blue) {
      z.setAttribute("class", "blue");
    } else if (userArray[i][j] == white) {
      z.setAttribute("class", "white");
    } else if (userArray[i][j] == grey) {
      z.setAttribute("class", "grey");
    }
    document.getElementById("row" + i).appendChild(z);

  }
}

document.querySelector("#gridTable").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if(event.target.classList.contains("blue")){
 event.target.className = 'grey';
  }else if(event.target.classList.contains("grey")){
 event.target.className = 'white'
  }else if(event.target.classList.contains("white")){
 event.target.className = 'blue'
  }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything

Comment: Just tested your code and it worked for me. I'm editing the answer with working code for both issues you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you happened to need more than 3 colours, you could use an array and cycle through it. Note that I in the following example I used both class and data attribute to separate the logic between the view and the data, but it is quite irrelevant here since class and data are the same (i.e. blue, grey, white). I just put it here for guidelines in case classes looked like 'blueTile' 'greyTile', in which case you would have to use objects to store both the colour name and the class associated with it. I also changed the css a bit.

It could look like this ([full working example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obgrpmrj/1))

```
var z = "";
var blue = "blue";
var white = "white";
var grey = "grey";
var colours = [blue, white, grey];

...


for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  //output the row tag
  var y = document.createElement("TR");
  y.setAttribute("id", "row" + i);
  document.getElementById("gridTable").appendChild(y)

  for (j = 0; j < userArray.length; j++) {

    ///output the td tag
    var z = document.createElement("TD");

    z.classList.add('tile');
    setElementColour(z, userArray[i][j]);
    var t = document.createTextNode(userArray[i][j]);
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("row" + i).appendChild(z);

  }

}

document.querySelector("#gridTable").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    cycleElementColour(event.target);
});


function setElementColour(element, colour) {
    setElementColourClass(element, colour);
    setElementColourData(element, colour);
}


function setElementColourData (element, colour) {
    var elementColour = element.getAttribute('data-colour');
    if (elementColour === colour) {
        return;
    }

    element.setAttribute('data-colour', colour);
}


function setElementColourClass (element, colour) {
    colours.forEach(function (colour) {
        element.classList.remove(colour);
    });

    element.classList.add(colour);
}


function cycleThroughValues(currentValue, availableValues) {
    var currentValueIndex = availableValues.indexOf(currentValue);
    var nextValueIndex = (currentValueIndex + 1) % availableValues.length;
    return availableValues[nextValueIndex];
}


function cycleElementColour (element) {
    var currentColour = element.getAttribute('data-colour');
    var newColour = cycleThroughValues(currentColour, colours);
    setElementColour(element, newColour);
}
```

Comment: This answer is typical example of overengineering. I like the approach. It is just not needed. Actually it can confuse the author of the question, instead of help him.

Comment: Damn.. Got to admit you are right. I never know  when to stop